# Find collision time given distance and speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Suppose I have an object A at position x = 0 and object B at position x = 16.

Suppose A have this code:

```c#
public class Move : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float speed = 0.04f;

    Update()
    {
       transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

My question is: how to evaluate how many seconds (precisely) will it take for A to collide with B?

---

If I apply the formula S = S0 + vt, it won't work correctly, because I don't know how to measure how many frames it will pass in a second to exactly measure what speed is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't do that. Your code is currently **framerate-dependent** so the object moves faster if you have a higher framerate!

Rather use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

> This property provides the time between the current and previous frame.

to convert your speed from `Unity Units / frame` into `Unity Units / second`

```c#
transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

this means the object now moves with `0.04 Unity Units / second` (framerate-independent).

---

Then I would say the required time in seconds is simply

```c#
var distance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - objectB.transform.position.x);
var timeInSeconds = distance / speed;
```

Though .. this obviously still assumes by "collide" you mean at the same position (at least on the X axis) .. you could also take their widths into account since their surfaces will collide earlier than this ;)

```c#
var distance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - objectB.transform.position.x) - (objectAWidth + objectBWidth);
var timeInSeconds = distance / speed;
```